# Why is the bad question ban so fierce?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have asked about 4 bad questions, so I got an automatic ban.

I have since improved many of the questions, and they are still banning me.

As well, I have gained about 250 rep since I got this ban, and I'm still banned.

What can I do to lift this automatic ban?

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions?

Comment: 1, or maybe 2...

Comment: The answer will not have changed since the last time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166233/why-am-i-still-banned-on-stackoverflow-com

Comment: If only there was some collection of questions that were frequently asked that would cover this situation... Bah, that's just crazy talk!

Comment: The reason I didn't consider a duplicate is because of the effort and motivation I've put into this with no results.

Comment: @Alex.Piechowski The problem is that the answer still remains the same. :( No user nor a mod can tell you when exactly you will be unbanned. But if you keep it up, at some point you will. It's great that your effort is paying off in terms of rep. You'll get there. Good luck.

Comment: @Alex.Piechowski your questions could use improvement, still. Take [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015471/php-json-print-out), for instance. The title doesn't indicate what the problem is about, at all. And your question doesn't express the goal (to sort by the credits key) clearly either. It leaves too much on the reader to figure out what your issue is, and it's unlikely to provide benefit to future users, in its current state. So, continue to improve your questions until they are good (or even better!), not just acceptable.

Comment: Thank you @CarlVeazey, I have made edits to your specifications.

Comment: @Alex.Piechowski that's definitely a lot better, I'll go ahead and change the title for you too and I think you'll have a pretty solid question there.

Comment: @CarlVeazey, is there a way I can gift you bounty or anything? Also, are there any improvements to my poor copywrite question?

Comment: @CarlVeazey, also my option explicit question is really poor as well. By the way, with all the suggested edits I have finally made it back to unbanned. I just want to make my questions as helpful as possible to the community after I messed up

Comment: @Alex.Piechowski glad to hear you're unbanned! Keep on the right track! To pay me back, read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) now, and whenever you're about to ask a question, always re-read it to make sure you're following his suggestions. And from now on pay it forward to others who get in trouble and need help.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: I have read Jon's blog entry and asked my first question off of it. My question was answered in just about 5 minutes. Thank you, you have pointed out my flaws as an asker and helped me improve.

Comment: @Pachonk that's fantastic! I'm glad to hear it and keep it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, if you haven't already, read **[this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)** ***thoroughly***.

Now, the key is to improve your existing questions so that they are upvoted an reopened. If you have deleted questions that you think are improvable, flag one of your existing posts asking for a moderator to undelete your questions for you (since you can't see them), because you want to improve them.

While answering does help, it won't solve the ban in all cases. Improve your bad questions, so that they are not as bad, and the ban will be lifted.

Comment: And, if possible, make your good questions even better. Don't just focus on the bad ones.

Comment: Still, gaining 250 rep has to count something here. And we all know that editing heavily downvoted questions is most often an exercise in futility, don't we?

Comment: @Bart: That's also true. Again, we don't know the exact mechanics. So just **improve in general!**

Comment: @Pekka: It probably is, however, that's the only way I know to lift the ban. It *does* strike me odd that with 250 rep he's still question banned.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Most often, yes. Though there are exceptions. And given that we don't know the exact situation, 250 rep might count, but perhaps have put him just below the threshold. Whatever that is.

Comment: I appreciate whoever upvoted my other question. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015471/php-json-print-out